# How to use the ```setContent``` method of Bootstrap 5.2 popper component using jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5, popper

Can someone please show me how to call the `setContent` method of **popper** component in Bootstrap 5.2 using jQuery?

While calling the `show` method is as simple as `$("#myElement").popper('show')` the same does not seem to be the case for the `setContent` method which takes an object parameter.

Bootstrap documentation only give example using native DOMElement as below

```
// getOrCreateInstance example
const popover = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#example') // Returns a Bootstrap popover instance

// setContent example
myPopover.setContent({
  '.popover-header': 'another title',
  '.popover-body': 'another content'
})
```

PLEASE NOTE: In the sample the const variable declared is *popover*, but the call is shown on a variable *myPopover* which adds to further confusion for a novice like me.

The documentation says Bootstrap 5.2 is independent of jQuery but can still work just like it use to with previous versions.

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
const popover = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#example') 
popover.setContent({
  '.popover-header': 'another title',
  '.popover-body': 'another content'
})
popover.show()
```